# error in sql query for displaying records from table

Tags: php, sql

I am trying the following query and it works fine

```
$sqlmsg=$Db1->query("SELECT COUNT(username)  AS tmsgs FROM messages");

$tempmsg=$Db1->fetch_array($sqlmsg);

$thismemberinfo['msg']=$tempmsg[tmsgs];
```

display the output

```
$thismemberinfo[msg]
```

While when try to run the following query for the same table, it gives me errors:

```
$sqlmsg=$Db1->query("SELECT COUNT(read)  AS tmsgs FROM messages");

$tempmsg=$Db1->fetch_array($sqlmsg);

$thismemberinfo['msg']=$tempmsg[tmsgs];
```

values for read are [0 or 1 ] always.

Follwing error is generated when i run the 2nd query:

Database error: Invalid SQL: SELECT COUNT(read) AS tmsgs FROM messages
MySQL Error: 1064 (You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'read) AS tmsgs FROM messages' at line 1)

### Session halted.

**TASK That i want to acheieve:**

I have a table where user messages are stored,read= 1 , unread =0 ,
I want to display unread messages from each user , when he logs in.

thinking of something like this

```
 $sqlmsg=$Db1->query("SELECT COUNT(read)  AS tmsgs FROM messages WHERE username=$username");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`read` is a [`reserved word(s)`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) in MySQL. You need to wrap them using backticks.

It should be..

```
$sqlmsg=$Db1->query("SELECT COUNT(`read`)  AS tmsgs FROM messages");
```

Comment: $sqlmsg=$Db1->query("SELECT COUNT(`read`)  AS tmsgs FROM messages WHERE username='$username' AND `read`=0");

Thanks this one worked for me, backticks worked fine :) ,, Thanks All

Comment: @user3577691, It is better to avoid such column names for your table. If you have just started creating tables and stuff , you could very well rename them too.

Comment: actually, its existing db, i just wanted to display some values out of that. so cant change anthing, unless i know the whole structure , it take time :) .. Thanks all for help

Answer (score 1):

read is a reserved keyword
use backtick for it as

```
`read`
```